# Hi, How to get all column data using Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I created a script to retrieve all column data( Names) but when i check the logs, it;s displaying last name of the page for all 100 pages.

Have 100 pages of info and want to see all names under identity name column,

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a column with last name and then one with name, and so when you go and ask for name it might be focusing on last name rather than something like full name.